# Is it possible to use Snap Scrolling?

Tags: plugins, css

I would like to add snap points to my WP website, but am not sure how or if it's even possible. The CSS properties for such an animation aren't accessible on WordPress.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: "CSS properties for such an animation aren't accessible on WordPress" - you can put any properties you like in a theme. Is this for a page that's assembled from lots of pieces of content, e.g. a long scrolling front page drawn from multiple custom post types, or is it for pages that are entirely put together by users? I'd guess you can make snap scrolling Gutenberg blocks to put in your pages?